# Pushouts in Top

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, category-theory, equivalence-relations, limits-colimits

Consider the following pushout diagram in the category $\text{Top}$:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>{f}>> C\\
@V{g}VV @VVV \\
B @>{}>> P = B \coprod_A C
\end{CD}
$$
where $f$ is a surjection and $g$ is an injection. Does the following claim hold?

**Claim:** $P$ is a quotient of $B$.

**My Thoughts:** Define a relation on $B$ as follows: 
$$
b \sim b' \iff b=g(a), b'=g(a') \ \text{and} \ f(a)=f(a'). 
$$
To me, this feels like it should be true, but I've no idea how to prove it.

I'd also really appreciate some strong pushout references!

Moveover, suppose that $B$ is itself a quotient space, i.e $B = D/\sim$. Can we thus say that $P$ is a quotient of $D$?

Comment: If $g$ is the identitity, the map $B\to P$ is $f$ (up to homeomorphism), so you should probably require $f$ to be a quotient map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true in general.  For instance, if $g$ is an isomorphism, then so is its pushout $C\to P$, so $B\to P$ is a quotient map iff $f$ is a quotient map.

On the other hand, if you assume $f$ is a quotient map, then the map $B\to P$ is also a quotient map (and there is no need to assume $g$ is injective).  This is pretty much immediate from the following characterization of quotient maps: a continuous surjection $p:X\to Y$ is a quotient map iff for any $Z$, a function $Y\to Z$ is continuous iff its composition with $p$ is continuous.

In this case, let $p:B\to P$ and $q:C\to P$ be the maps of the pushout diagram and suppose $h:P\to Z$ is any function.  Then by the universal property of pushouts, $h$ is continuous iff the compositions $hp$ and $hq$ are both continuous.  Since $f$ is a quotient map, $hq$ is continuous iff $hqf$ is continuous.  But $hqf=hpg$, so $h$ is continuous iff $hp$ and $hpg$ are both continuous.  Since continuity of $hp$ implies continuity of $hpg$, $h$ is continuous iff $hp$ is continuous.  Thus $p$ is a quotient map.

If $B$ is additionally a quotient of some other space $D$, then $P$ will be a quotient of $D$ as well, since a composition of two quotient maps is a quotient map.

Comment: Thanks for this! Any idea where I could find a reference for this result?